# Google sheets Sort and Get Unique values of multiples columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have in GoogleSheets  data in 4 different columns, I would like to sort and get all unique values from the 4 columns.

```
 column A    column B       column C   column D
               0496                     1111
  0661         0496                     AB0001
               0919          0345
```

This is my try:

```
=(sort(unique(TRIM({text_format!B2:B27800,text_format!C2:C27800,text_format!D2:D27800, text_format!E2:E27800}))))
```

How i can make it work and get all my data in one colum?

Expected results

```
Column E:
0661
0496
0919
0345
AB0001
1111
```

Comment: Show us some of sample data.

Comment: Oh! I have posted my answer before your editing. Give a try on my answer then let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a sorted list of unique values in `text_format!A2:D`, use this:

`=sort(unique(flatten(text_format!A2:D)))`

To remove leading and trailing whitespace before sorting, use this:

`=sort(unique(flatten(trim(text_format!A2:D))))`

The latter formula will get an extra zero-length text string as the first value.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,B2:E27800),"@"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, I get error message text join is longer then 50000 characters. My dataset quite big

Comment: Yes. Textjoin() has character limitation. Then we need think some other ways.